# center text and checkmark of CheckedTextView

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, checkedtextview

Layout i implemented like below picture :

[image]

And code I used is :

```
 <CheckedTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/big_green_btn_normal"
        android:checkMark="@drawable/check_circle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/register_tempClickStaffingAgreement" />
```

This what i wanted,like the following picture :

[image]

Share some idea to customize it but not with custom linear or any other layout..i want a single custom view or checkedTextView...any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks..!!

Comment: i don't know why u guys had down voted but i don't care for that....if u guys have downvoted my question,,,then probably u know the answer....so tell me or share it guys.....i already had wasted a lot of time on this

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Please try below code to implement checkview as you mentioned :

```
<CheckedTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:checkMark="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tempclick Staffing Agreement"
        android:textAlignment="gravity" />
```

Thanks..!!

Comment: Thanks @AndiGeeky, your answer is very helpful to me...can you please align the checkmark alongwith textview....and thank you again

Comment: @ Vikram Singh : Did not get your point .. Will you please explain more..!!

Comment: i just want to align the checkmark along with text like done in this application( 2 Image) https://github.com/pnc/IconButton

Comment: @ Vikram Singh : Please add image url..!

Comment: here is the image url,https://github.com/pnc/IconButton/blob/master/images/demo.png?raw=true

Comment: @VikramSingh Did you find the solution?

Comment: @VikramSingh: I have not tried yet. Can you please add question with more details and send me link?

Comment: @AndiGeeky The question is to make the tick mark center along with the text (temp click staffing agreement) . Right now the text alone is centered but the tick mark is in right most.

Comment: @AndiGeeky OP has posted a sample pic here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pnc/IconButton/master/images/demo.png  In this pic the search lens icon is also centered along with the text. He wants the tick mark in center in the similar way.

Comment: @user3705478, i don't thing it can be done, either u have user two view or go for a custom view like the shared image.

Comment: Wow Google dev vertically stretch custom checkMark for CheckedTextView

Comment: not giving same effect with drawable start. Text is slightly shifted