# How to center the checkbox and text of checkedTextView in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, checkbox, checkedtextview

I have activity_choose_number1.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_choose_number1" />
```

This is content_choose_number1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.abc.abc.ChooseNumber1"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_choose_number1">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/listViewNumberList"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is secnumsinglechoice.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:checkMark="@null"
    android:drawableStart="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    tools:targetApi="ice_cream_sandwich"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:linksClickable="false"
    android:checked="false"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp" />
```

The secnumsinglechoice.xml is copy paste of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice and made some changes.

Now what I need is to center align the checkbox and text of secnumusingchoice.xml. I also need the checkbox to be left side of text in each item of list view

Things I tried
1) If I do drawableLeft, it creates space between text and checkbox, but doesn't make both to be centered
2) If I add android:textAlignment="center" then still it center aligns the text but not the check box .
3) I tried here [center text and checkmark of CheckedTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251242/center-text-and-checkmark-of-checkedtextview/33251603?noredirect=1#comment66696546_33251603)  but I would like to try here with more code.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't use `checkbox` and `textview` separately? Try to use `CheckedTextView` is quite hard to align checkbox and text..

Comment: @MikeM. Yep tried that I that still didn't work.

Comment: @RoShanShan If I use separately how can I choose the text value when it's corresponding check box is chosen? Could you provide link for some reference please? Thx.

Comment: @MikeM. In this question you see the tick mark to the right. It is not center aligned like the text. I want my both text and tick mark to be center aligned.

Comment: @MikeM. Lets say in this image I want both the checkbox and text to be center aligned  http://kb4dev.com/images/13

Comment: @MikeM. Could you please provide the code as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/ckb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEduName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="ABC"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Result

[image]

Comment: The problem is the number of options shown to user is dynamic. For example, for some users it could be 5 records, for some it could be 10 records etc. I cannot hard code the options and we do not know the number of options that we will be getting.

Comment: I think that 's the reason why you use listview with dynamic data.

Answer (score 1):

To get everything to center correctly, we'll subclass `CheckedTextView`, and override its `onDraw()` method to first measure the combined `Drawable` and text widths and paddings, and then translate the `Canvas` accordingly before calling the `super` method to actually do the draw.

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.text.Layout;

public class CenteredCheckedTextView extends CheckedTextView {
    public CenteredCheckedTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CenteredCheckedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (getCompoundDrawables()[0] == null) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
        else {
            // Left drawable and paddings width
            final float dw = getCompoundDrawables()[0].getIntrinsicWidth() + 
                             getPaddingLeft() + getCompoundDrawablePadding();
            // Text width
            final float tw = getMaxLineMeasure();

            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate((getWidth() - (dw + tw)) / 2f, 0f);
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    private float getMaxLineMeasure() {
        final Layout layout = getLayout();
        final int lines = getLineCount();
        float m = 0, max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i) {
            m = getPaint().measureText(getText(),
                                       layout.getLineStart(i),
                                       layout.getLineEnd(i));
            if (m > max) {
                max = m;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

`CheckedTextView` has a `checkMarkGravity` attribute that determines on which end it places the `checkMark` `Drawable`, but it's not public, for some odd reason, so we'll just use the `drawableLeft`. For example:

```
<com.mycompany.myapp.CenteredCheckedTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle" />
```

You might need to slightly fiddle with the translation and/or width values in the custom class to get everything to line up with what looks centered to you, depending on what kind of transparent, intrinsic padding the `Drawable` has.

---

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Convincing. I haven't tried the solution yet. But when you say I need to slightly fiddle with the width values, will the alignment look non-centered if the app is used in a tablet or some other screen size?

Comment: I wasn't talking so much about screen size, but more about the drawable itself possibly having transparent padding on either side that might make it seem a little off-center. Even the circular shape in the screenshot makes it look a little right-shifted to me. Just visual preference, really. Nothing major.